# How does elementary row-multiplication change the left eigenvector of an irreducible nonnegative matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Let $M$ be an irreducible nonnegative matrix and $E$ be some diagonal matrix where all diagonal elements are positive. It is clear that $EM$ is another irreducible nonnegative matrix. Letting $\rho(M)$ denote the spectral radius of $M$, Perron-Frobenius tells us that since $M$ is irreducible and nonnegative, there exists a unique positive row vector $v$ such that $vM = \rho(M)v$ and the sum of the components of $v$ is $1$. Analogously, $EM$ has a unique positive row vector $w$ such that $wEM = \rho(EM)w$ and the sum of the components of $w$ is $1$.

My question is: *What is the relation between $v$ and $w$, and can this relation be expressed using $E$ and $M$?*

I have considered using the square root of $E$ and its inverse, and have also tried to rework the question into a differential equation where the elements of $E$ change smoothly, but these ideas seem to be going nowhere.

Maybe there is a special case if $\rho(EM) = \rho(M)$?